# Why for simple roots in Lie algebras the master formula reduces to one integer?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The master formula for two generic weights (roots) is 
$$ 2 \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} }{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} }=q-p $$ 
but if we require that the roots are simple then this reduces to 
$$ 2 \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} }{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} }=q \neq 0 $$ 
i.e. $p=0$. Why is this and why $q\neq0$?

[image]

P.S. I understand why  $q\neq0$ since it comes straight out from the requirement that the roots are simple.

Comment: Yes, I copied it wrong. But still I cannot understand the main part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your doubt can be found in chapter $8$ of [Lie algebras and particle physics](http://mural.uv.es/rusanra/Lie%20Algebras%20in%20Particle%20Physics%202%C2%AA%20ed%20-%20From%20Isospin%20to%20Unified%20Theories%20%28Georgi,%201999%29.pdf) by Georgi.

In particular, a simple root is a root that cannot be written as a sum of positive roots.

Given two simple roots $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ then $\vec{a}- \vec{b}$ is *not* a root, otherwise - say $\vec{b}$ is larger - $\vec{b} = \vec{a} + (\vec{b}-\vec{a})$ and $\vec{b}$ would be not simple.

So, since $\vec{a}- \vec{b}$ is not a root you have
$$ 2 \frac{\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}}{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}} = q-p$$

with $p = 0$, just because the combination of roots you have chosen is not a root. Recall that $p$ is the number of times you apply a (negative) root to your weight representation state by $E_{-a}$.

Comment: thanks. I do not have that particular book but I uploaded a pic from the one I have. I agree with what you say but I do not understand yet why $p=0$! If $p$ is that then what is $q$ (the equivalent for the "lowest weight state"?)

Comment: if you click on the link of the book you get a pdf

Comment: In any case, do you remeber how $p$ is defined? given the $SU(2)$ algebra defined by a root $\vec{a}$, $p$ is the maximum (non-negative) integer such that $(E_{-a})^p\vert \mu, R\rangle \neq 0$. For a simple root applied to the state (in the adjoint rep) $\vert E_{b} \rangle$ such integer is zero, since $\vec{a}-\vec{b}$ is not a root. (I am very sorry, my notation had $p$ and $q$ exchanged, now I fixed it)

Comment: Yes, I remember, I agree. I am confused with this when we are going to simple roots. $p$ tells me how many times I can apply the "raising operator" before I get zero, this is the maximum number of $q$ characterizes the maximum root or weight. But if $p=0$ then for a simple root it means I cannot have a raising operator?

Comment: No, what is zero is the number related to the lowering operator. Meaning that starting from a state given by a simple root, you cannot descend along the direction of another simple root.

Comment: Ah, so I guess this does not apply to $SU(2)$ because it only has one simple root, right? I need bigger ranks to see this working.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $SU(2)$ is to small to see this working, Cartan sub-algebra is one dimensional, etc.

Comment: The book you sent me seems to have the clearest of the explanations. Thanks.